# Unable to load AWS credentials Error when accessing dynamoDB (local) with java

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I have installed the local version of dynamoDB, and set up a maven java project to access the DB. When i run the code i get the below error. Since i have installed the server in local (it runs son localhost:8000), i dont have any credentials to provide...
Any idea how to solve it?

```
import java.util.Iterator;

import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;

import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;
import com.amazonaws.client.builder.AwsClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.Table;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.TableCollection;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.exceptions.DynamoDBLocalServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.embedded.DynamoDBEmbedded;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.DynamoDBProxyServer;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.ListTablesResult;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         AmazonDynamoDB client = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard().withEndpointConfiguration(
                    // we can use any region here
                    new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000", "us-west-2"))
                    .build();
         DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(client);
         //dynamoDB.listTables();
         TableCollection<ListTablesResult> list = dynamoDB.listTables();

         Iterator<Table> iterator = list.iterator();

            System.out.println("Listing table names");

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Table table = iterator.next();
                System.out.println(table.getTableName());
            }


         System.out.println("over");
    }



}
```

Error is

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain
    at com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProviderChain.getCredentials(AWSCredentialsProviderChain.java:131)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.getCredentialsFromContext(AmazonHttpClient.java:1115)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.runBeforeRequestHandlers(AmazonHttpClient.java:764)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:728)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:721)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:704)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:672)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:654)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:518)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.doInvoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1831)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1807)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.listTables(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:1123)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.ListTablesCollection.firstPage(ListTablesCollection.java:46)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.PageIterator.next(PageIterator.java:45)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.IteratorSupport.nextResource(IteratorSupport.java:87)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.internal.IteratorSupport.hasNext(IteratorSupport.java:55)
```

Answer (score 12):

Stumbled upon this when I was searching for the same problem. After half a day of wasting time, managed to solve the issue. Posting here in case anyone ever stumbles upon such situation again.

And the worst part? The solution I had to pierce through and experiment after going through thousands of pages, you would expect there to be some info about the problem. At the least, the documentation should have mentioned some note!

**The solution :**

[Configuring AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/v2/developer-guide/net-dg-config-creds.html) : go through that to set up some credential. Configure it as any random thing, it doesn't really matter.

Yeah, this was it!!

---

And for those ppl who are still lazy (like me ;-) ) to go through that, just follow the easiest of the methods :

1. Open the default config file : `~/.aws/credentials`
2. Change the values in it to anything (like empty string here)

   ```
   [default]
   aws_access_key_id=''
   aws_secret_access_key=''
   ```
3. Run the program. You can thank me later :D

Comment: what if there is no such directory as aws?

Comment: Create one I guess. Not sure. You'll have to experiment there.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue.  To get around when running tests locally, I have added few lines to set java System properties.

System.setProperty(ACCESS_KEY_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "accesskey");        System.setProperty(SECRET_KEY_SYSTEM_PROPERTY, "secretkey");

Answer (score 0):

As per the Amazon Web Services documentation, [Working with AWS Credentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html)

Official supported Java system properties are:

- aws.accessKeyId
- aws.secretKey

The following sets these system properties:

```
System.setProperty("aws.accessKeyId", "super-access-key");
System.setProperty("aws.secretKey", "super-secret-key");
```

This needs to be set before creating the Amazon DynamoDB client.